# Android Error : Launcher Dialog Dismiss Failed

Tags: android

I have created an app which runs fine on android API 22 (I have been using the same API level for debugging since start). Now I am testing on other devices with lower and higher API levels but the app crashes as soon as I start the app on lower API level API 19. (Haven't tested on higher ones yet)

The logcat shows this error for API 19

```
11-18 22:32:51.560 3388-3388/? E/HwLauncher: Launcher dialog dismiss failed : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 1 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog
11-18 22:32:51.810 2862-2879/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
11-18 22:32:51.820 2862-3190/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
11-18 22:32:51.820 2862-3386/? E/BroadcastQueue: processNextBroadcast log test
```

Build.grade :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The Launcher activity code is below:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        // Alert Box

        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder1.setTitle("Internet  not connected");
        builder1.setMessage("You need to connect WiFi/Mobile-Data run this app.");
        builder1.setCancelable(false);

        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                "Go to Settings",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        //////////////////////////////

        //WifiManager wifi =(WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo == null) {

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
        }

        else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    // Start your app main activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    // close this activity
                    finish();
                }
            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any issue with my target SDKversion?

Comment: Where do you dismiss the dialog?

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this way below?

```
if (networkInfo == null) {

        builder1.create();
        builder1.show();
    }
```

In the LogCat is there any other detailed information, such informing the line error?